# When I modify docx xml file [document.xml] with PHP QueryPath 2.1.2 changes are not visibile in actual test1.docx file, why?

Tags: php, xml, querypath

I am trying to learn how to modify .docx and .odt files with PHP [QueryPath] and when I run this script [below] from cmd.exe [command line] on WAMP, on the command line it shows that changes that I want have been done and all text inside  tags have been changed, but when I open an actual docx file or its xml equivalent - none of the changes have been made. Why? And how can I rectify this? Thanks in advance.

```
    <?php

require 'src/QueryPath/QueryPath.php';

$file = 'zip://test1.docx#word/document.xml';

$doc = qp($file);

foreach($doc->find('w|t') as $item) {
        $item->text('BLABLABLA')->writeXML();
}


?>
```

Comment: You're not writing the changes back to the zip file, are you? The `zip://` protocol doesn't support writing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.querypath.org/docs/class_query_path.html#ac2ee9842d87e2a20fead454864b5d647) for `writeXML`:

> Write the document to a file path, if given, or to stdout (usually the client).

Since you're not passing anything to `writeXML` it's going to just display the modified XML, not save it to the file.

Also, you should modify the code to only call `writeXML` once, at the end of your script, i.e.

`$doc->writeXML($filename);`

Comment: Very fair point, plus he will have the additional problem that all his changes will be lost because he's using the `zip://` protocol which is read only.

Comment: So What protocol should I use to write to either .docx or .odt file? I am very new to this, please help me with examples of code! Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the answer to that offhand but you'll probably need to use the `ZipArchive` class to construct a new zip file and then save it. See http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php